# Object movement to a circular shape, with the grab of a VR controller?

Tags: unity, c#, virtual-reality

I have a HTC Vive VR set, which has a controller. I have a sphere object, which I want to rotate in a circular motion around my VR Player object, based on the controller grab and its movement. The controller should first grab the object, then it will move left or right, in a circular motion, based on the controller movement. How can I achieve this?

---

So far, I have made a sphere, with a parent. The parent position is updating with respect to my camera head, so I can move my sphere with my player. The sphere object should move with the controller, but in a circular motion. This has not been achieved, yet, and I really don't know how to do it.

I am able to grip the sphere object using a VRTK script, and I can freely move it, but I want to restrict its movement; much like in the illustrated figure, below:

[image]

Comment: I think a diagram might help here. There's lots of different ways I could imagine moving something along a circular path, depending on the size & orientation of that circle relative to the player & object. Are you effectively trying to move the object to the point closest to the VR controller while remaining constrained to this circular path? Is your problem in calculating that closest-point-on-circle, or in moving the object to that point?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for your comments. Actually i have get stuck in this problem from last one week.  Yes you are right, I want to move the object with my controller but in circular shape around my player object. And i am facing problem in both :"calculating that closest-point-on-circle" and " moving the object to that point". as you said. I am also updating my question with picture.

Comment: @DMGregory i have also added a picture, if you have any query please ask

Comment: @Gnemlock its ok

Comment: @DMGregory does the picture make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to restrict the usual spherical movement that occurs as you move the Vive controller around, to a sort of equatorial, planar movement. I'm going to assume that as in [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/149239/htc-vive-tutorial-unity), your Vive controllers and head are all part of the same transform hierarchy (what they call `CameraRig` there).

**Option A: If you can get the Vive Controller's rotation around the camera (rig).** Put sphere into a swivel which is an empty `GameObject`, having a transform only. Zero the sphere's local position in the inspector. Make sure swivel's `transform.position` tracks that of the head camera. Set sphere's `transform.localPosition=1` to move it slightly forward of the player's head. Set swivel's `transform.localEulerAngles.y` and `.z` to the same as the Vive controller's `transform.localEulerAngles`, but limit `transform.localEulerAngles.x = 0` on each sphere `Update()`. This prevents tilting (up/down) while maintaining heading (north/south/east/west) just like the Vive controller's `transform` to which it is attached.

**Option B: Possibly Simpler.** You want that plane / circle to be around your head, and I think it is never tilted (the validity of this answer relies on this fact). In every sphere `Update()`, set sphere's `transform.position.x` and `.z` to that of the Vive controller's `transform.position`, but set sphere's `transform.localPosition.y` equal to desired (head camera) `y`, every frame. You can also set the `transform.rotation` to the same as the Vive controller, if you need that.

**For both options A & B** These will superficially work, but you will find that if you look up or down then the sphere will get slightly closer or further away. This is because we are essentially projecting the sphere co-ordinates onto a flat circle. To prevent this i.e. to keep a fixed radius, set sphere's `transform.localPosition.z` to the distance you want, which might be the distance between the Vive controller and your camera, which is easy to compute, or you could always set it to, say, 1 unit.

**Option C**: **If the sphere is a child of the Vive controller GameObject.** Set Vive controller's `transform.localEulerAngles.x` (or *maybe* `.z`) `= 0` each frame. Provided your logic runs *after* the Vive controller's logic, this will do the trick of keeping your object on the circle. Assuming you don't care whether you limit the controller object or the sphere itself, this is the easiest method.

From a mathematical standpoint, we are really just projecting a sphere onto a plane. Between these varied approaches, you should be able to work to a solution. Feel free to ask questions, below.

Comment: Thanks for your response but answers(option A and b) doesn't make any sense, i guess. by setting only rotation of the sphere i can only maintain its  circular position as option 1 suggested. While for option B, the circle should be at head height but move able around 360 of the player using controller.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan About Option A, you are correct. I have edited the answer. About Option B, this should then do what you suggest, no? Lock it to a circle whose plane is perpendicular to the up-vector of the player's body and head. I've elaborated on both, in any case.

Comment: Hi arcane engineer, thanks for your valueable input, i have red your answer 3 or 4 times it seems applicable with some limitation which i will discuss you after the implementation. currently the first option i am implementing. i will let you know its hurdles or limitation soon

Comment: This is your first option, Right? : 1. Make an empty game object (swivel)
2. Make a sphere object, set it as a child to swivel object with zero position
3. Map cam head position to swivel position (update)
4. Set sphere local postion 1 (so that it comes ahead of the player)
5. Set y and z euler angles of the swivel same as controller but with x  euler angles = 0

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan Sounds roughly correct, not 100% sure about the axes in  step 5 but they should be right, otherwise try swapping x and z.

Comment: Thanks arcane engineer, i tried option A, its working but with a bug that each time i grab the sphere its change its rotation which is far from controller.

Comment: additionally i want to tell you that i only provide y value swivel.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0); to parent object(swivel) because setting z or x allowing sphere to move up and down or cross which is not required

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan OK super re y value. As for the other thing, "each time i grab the sphere its change its rotation which is far from controller" is not so clear to me. - Do you mean swivel changes rotation? or sphere? I thought it would not matter if the sphere changes rotation...

Comment: sorry silly me, maybe i am unable to explain the problem clearly. I mean i am rotating swivel object as above code suggested (through controller's y euler angle). but each time i grab object to rotate it, the object rotation jump at certain rotation. it not gripping (which actually rotation) precisely.

Comment: like if i try to grip the sphere it slight jump ahead (means rotate further) because i am setting swivel.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan I think I understand what you are seeing. So, when you pick up this object, it should be like in real life, e.g. if I hold a pencil pointing away from me, then if I turn, the pencil is still pointing away, right? And also I am understanding that in the moment you pick up the object, yes it is held, but it is not right in front of you (or wherever the controller is pointing) but rather rotated more or less around camera y axis than the controller itself?

Comment: I don't want to rotate my sphere all the time it should rotate on controller grip. so i grip the sphere i run this code swivel.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);, it slight jump (means rotation set but not at that precise location). altough it is rotating in circular shape very fine, thanks for this. you alomst done it

Comment: no actually the sphere representing day cycle of my environment. it will rotate around the player as day progress. and a user will be able to rotate through controller in order to change day time. he can grip the sphere to rotate it but the ball will not leave the circular path which is almost done using your answer but the problem is that as i tried to grip sphere it get rotation from controller which make the sphere object slight away from controller but its rotating fine

Comment: "make the sphere object slight away from controller" - along the circular path? or along a line facing out from the player? And is there just this one problem?

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan Can you send me a small screenshot of your transform hierarchy, please? Just so I can see how things are nested there. Then I can suggest a solution. Basically though, you need to calculate and store a y-rotational offset when you grab, and either subtract or add that to the y-rotation you are setting from the controller's transform, in each `Update()`. This should ensure that the object stays exactly where it should be, when we start.

Comment: Yes, you almost right and offset require to add or subtract, wait i am uploading video

Comment: I wonder, maybe Option B will be easier for you... then it will also work easily if sun / moon goes overhead...

Comment: here is the link  of problem https://youtu.be/XBO2RghgqLc

Comment: option b can be tricky (i dind't try this yet) due to fact that it will come near or far from my head.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59608/discussion-between-arcane-engineer-and-mohammad-faizan-khan).

Comment: Thanks you arcane engineer for your support, Your option B didn't work for me while Option A worked with little changes. I set my swivel object rotation using this (with offset as you told)  swivel.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.localEulerAngles.y+offset, 0)

Comment: Yes i have already done that thanks for your kind support.